# Prove that the series is convergent: 1- (1+1/3)/2 + (1+1/3+1/5)/3-.....

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I can see that this is an alternating series with the $n$-th term $$(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1+\frac13+\frac15+\cdots+ \frac{1}{2n-1}}{n}.$$

What test can I apply to show that it converges?

Also, it converges absolutely and not conditionally, right?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It converges to $\bigg(\dfrac\pi4\bigg)^2$

Comment: I'm very curious to know how you found that limit. Please do tell me!

Comment: $\dfrac11+\dfrac13+\dfrac15+\ldots+\dfrac1{2n-1}~ = ~\bigg(\dfrac11+\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\dfrac14+\ldots+\dfrac1{2n}\bigg) - \bigg(\dfrac12+\dfrac14+\ldots+\dfrac1{2n}\bigg)$ $=H_{2n}-\dfrac{H_n}2$, where $H_k$ is the k-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Now all that's left to do is to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{H_{2n}}n = \dfrac{5\pi^2}{48}-\dfrac{\ln^22}4$, and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{H_n}n = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}-\dfrac{\ln^22}2$. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You realized that you were dealing with an alternating serires, why don't you try the alternating series test first?

To see whether the series converges absolutely or not, you can compare with some well known series, for example the harmonic series $\sum\frac1n$.

Comment: I don't know what the alternating series test is. Can you please tell me the statement?

Comment: @Diya, wiki is a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Thank you! I got it from here.